# OpenCl Kernel to OpenGL compute shader

Tags: opengl, opencl

I have an openCL program which uses some kernels. Now I have to convert it to openGL. I came across compute shaders. But they were launched recently with OpenGL 4.3 so, its support will not be that much. So, is there any other options in OpenGL which can be used for such task.

My requirement is this because I want to use it in iOS which has OpenCL only in private mode.

Comment: Because of performance issues? Have you tried interoperability?  You dont have to send data through pci-e this way.

Comment: Or, you can use other shaders such as pixel-geometry-fragment as in this program http://www.catzilla.com/ They do fluid computation in opengl shaders.

Comment: Generally speaking: No, there aren't. Specifically speaking: I don't know, since you haven't shown any kernel code.

Comment: What's wrong with OpenCL - OpenGL interop?

Comment: @datenwolf It rather sounds like he wants to completely remove OpenCL dependency (for whatever reasons) instead of using his OpenCL computed stuff in OpenGL.

Answer (score 1):

You can go the old school way with OpenGL, like it was done before CUDA came out. See http://www.mathematik.uni-dortmund.de/~goeddeke/gpgpu/ for a tutorial.

However i have to warn you, doing GPGPU with OpenGL is very tricky and a lot work. From personal experience i'd have to advise against it, expect to spend at least 100 hours before getting good results.